# how do pass $res from codeigniter model to my ajax function in view?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to verify user details from the table.My model looks like this:

```
public function validate_login(){
$this->db->where(
array(
'login_username' => $this->input->post('username'),
'login_password' =>$this->input->post('password'))
);
$query = $this->db->get('login')->num_rows();
if ($query > 0){
$res = true;
}
else{
$res = false;
}
return $res;
}
```

Here, when I try to echo $res, it does not bring any information on my view. My Controller looks:

```
 function validate_login()
    {
                $res = $this->bizmanager->validate_login();

                echo $res;

        }
```

This is where I want to pass the results from Model as an object and then help me to direct which page to load. My function in view is:

```
 $.ajax({
         type:"post",
          url: base_url + 'home/validate_login',//URL changed 
         data:{ 
              'username':username, 
              'password':password},
         success:function(data){                  
         if (result == true)
            {
            window.location ="home/home";
             }
         else{
            window.location ="home/load_register";
             }
          } 
       }); 

     $('#frmlogin').each(function()
        {
        this.reset();
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing everything right, but when you echo `true` or `false` it cannot be read by ajax response. Instead of setting `$res` to `true` `false`, set it to `1` and `0`.

```
public function validate_login(){
    $this->db->where(array(
                'login_username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'login_password' =>$this->input->post('password'))
                );
    $query = $this->db->get('login')->num_rows();
    if ($query > 0){
        $res = 1;
    }
    else{
        $res = 0;
    }
    return $res;
}
```

**jQuery Code :**

`data` variable of success callback will have your `$res`. You don't need to pass it explicitly.

If `$res` is `1` it will redirect to "home/home" else to "home/load_register"

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url: base_url + 'home/validate_login',//URL changed 
    data:{ 
      'username':username, 
      'password':password
    },
    success:function(data){                  
        if (data === '1') {
            window.location ="home/home";
        } else {
            window.location ="home/load_register";
        }
    }
});
$('#frmlogin').each(function() {
    this.reset();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It has helped a lot. I am new to Codeigniter. How now do I pass that value to view function? So that if the value is not 1 or is the condition will work? Thank you again.

Comment: @MosesMwicigi You don't need to pass it explicitly.  success:function(data), your data will be available in data  variable of ajax success. plz check my jquery code too.

Comment: @MosesMwicigi check edit answer with little more detail about what my jquery code is doing.

Comment: Thank you @Touheed Khan. It has resolved my challenge. I am very grateful!

Comment: @MosesMwicigi great to hear that mate.
Plz accept my answer.

Comment: here is link http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png about how to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Model

```
public function validate_login(){
      $this->db->where(
                    array(
                    'login_username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'login_password' =>$this->input->post('password'))
                  );
      $query = $this->db->get('login')->num_rows();
      if ($query > 0){
          $res = 1;
      }else{
          $res = 0;
      }
      return $res;
}
```

Your controller code will like

```
    function validate_login()
    {
             $data = $this->bizmanager->validate_login();
             return json_encode($data);
    }
```

View code

```
$.ajax({
     type:"post",
     dataType : "json",
     url: base_url + 'home/validate_login',//URL changed 
     data:{ 'username':username, 'password':password},
     success:function(data){                  
         if (data=='1')
         { 
            window.location ="home/home";
         }else{
            window.location ="home/load_register";
         }
      } 
}); 

$('#frmlogin').each(function(){
    this.reset();
});
```